# OSError: [Errno 63] File name too long

Tags: qgis, python, qgis2web

I am a newbie trying to create an interactive map on my website about religious buildings of some city. I created a list of 60 churches in Google Maps and downloaded it as KML. Then I imported it to QGIS and now I got the following error, when I am trying to export with qgis2web plug-in. I couldn't find a solution online, or figure out what the problem is.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/Users/paksoy/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/maindialog.py", line 337, in previewMap
              preview_file = self.createPreview()
              File "/Users/paksoy/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/maindialog.py", line 299, in createPreview
              return writer.write(self.iface,
              File "/Users/paksoy/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/leafletWriter.py", line 90, in write
              self.preview_file = self.writeLeaflet(
              File "/Users/paksoy/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/leafletWriter.py", line 261, in writeLeaflet
              useOSMB) = writeVectorLayer(layer, safeLayerName,
              File "/Users/paksoy/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/leafletLayerScripts.py", line 125, in writeVectorLayer
              useShapes) = getLayerStyle(layer, safeLayerName, interactive,
              File "/Users/paksoy/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/leafletStyleScripts.py", line 41, in getLayerStyle
              pattern) = getSymbolAsStyle(symbol, markerFolder,
              File "/Users/paksoy/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/leafletStyleScripts.py", line 225, in getSymbolAsStyle
              shutil.copy(sl.path(), path)
              File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/shutil.py", line 418, in copy
              copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
              File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/shutil.py", line 264, in copyfile
              with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
             OSError: [Errno 63] File name too long: 'base64: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'
```

Comment: use a shorter file name

Comment: That is the problem. I don't get which files name to fix.

Comment: If you decode the base64 string, you get an svg symbol: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="religious-christian" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="15" height="15" viewBox="0 0 15 15">
  <path fill="param(fill) #000" fill-opacity="param(fill-opacity)" stroke="param(outline) #fff" stroke-width="param(outline-width) 0" stroke-opacity="param(outline-opacity)" id="rect3338" d="M6,0.9552V4H3v3h3v8h3V7h3V4H9V1&#xA;&#x9;c0-1-0.9776-1-0.9776-1H6.9887C6.9887,0,6,0,6,0.9552z"/>
</svg>`

Comment: So I don't know why, where or how, but instead of using the encoded symbol, it is believing to have a file path.